# Cómo abrir el navegador al ejecutar archivo html con visual Studio en linux

Tags: html, visual-studio, linux, ubuntu

Pues me gustaría que al ejecutar (f5) un archivo html en visual studio (2019) se abriera el navegador para mostrar el resultado de la página pero debe faltar alguna configuración, probablemente la ruta que debe ser leída que no es sino la del archivo que tenga abierto para editar. Alguien puede arrojar alguna luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La opcion mas recomendada para esto es usar en servidor web local de pruebas, en VS CODE hay una opcion que va muy bien:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer

Hay otra opcion que es desde la terminal de vscode o bash ejecutar este comando

```
firefox archivo.html
```

en este caso es para firefox